# html5 video tag not working in firefox for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, firefox, mime-types

For my Rails 4.2 app, my `video_tag` for HTML5 is working fine for Safari & Chrome, but I get `No video with supported format and MIME type found` in Firefox.

Here is my view:

```
<%= video_tag("preroll.webm", "preroll.ogv", "preroll.mp4", controls: true, size: "480x360", poster: "prerollposter.png") %>
```

Here is my controller `show` action:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any(:html, :m4v, :ogv, :webm) {
    }
  end
end
```

Here is my `mime_types.rb` file:

```
Mime::Type.register "video/webm", :webm
Mime::Type.register "video/ogg", :ogv
Mime::Type.register "video/mp4", :m4v
```

In `application.html.haml`, I have:

`%meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/`

In my terminal, I've done...

`rake assets:precompile`

...and I've continually refreshed my firefox browser and `cntl-c`'ed out of the local server every time.

I'm new at embedding video into a Rails app, so I'm wondering what the Rails equivalent of `.htaccess` might be (Is it actually `mime_types.rb`?).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.  I think I'd read somewhere previously that the Rails `video_tag` has some problems, but I'm not sure if that is the cause of Firefox not working here.  Thanks so much!